# Old Android Lock Screen - How is it designed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk

Any idea on how the old android lock screen was designed. The one that existed in 2.2, 2.3 etc. You can slide the left image to to the right to unlock it. Similarly, you can slide the right image to the left to take a photo.

Any idea how this was developed?

I am assuming that an onTouchListener was implemented on two images which moves according to your touch. However, How do you end up positioning the images and so on. Anyone worked on a project like this before?

Comment: You could pull `framework-res.apk` file and look at the layout files to find out about the positioning/XML portion of it. If it's deodexed, then you may be able to use dex2jar to decode classes.dex and then use jd-gui to read the jar file which may be proguarded and then you're screwed from that approach as far as the java goes. It's an idea anyway, but java-wise, you'd probably be better off just playing around with it (and using the docs) to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

On my device it was "right to left" to toggle silent-  You might have a phone with non-stock Android, in which case the OEM could have customized their own lock screen.

That said, Android is open source, so you can look at the lock screen [source code](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java&q=LockScreen.java&type=cs) and see how they implemented it :)